# I tried to create a lambda function and try to return tuple values but I am getting generator object error

Tags: python, lambda, tuples

```
val_by_vec = lambda x ,t=(): print(next(x ,t[i]) for t[i] in range(0,len(t)))

val_by_vec('Raj',((2,"Raj"),(3,"Amalu")))
```

output:

```
<generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002A1ABC5FEB0>
```

expected output:

```
('Raj', (2, 'Raj'))
('Raj', (3, 'Amalu'))
```

Comment: Try printing the contents: `for ele in generator: print(ele)`

Comment: Based on your code, the answer below might do what you actually want -- but doesn't do what you said you want. Do you want a lambda expression that *returns* a tuple or do you want a lambda expression that *prints* a tuple? "print" and "return" are not synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

`next` would only ever return the next object from that iteration anyway so it doesn't make sense to use it, you can just unpack a list comprehension

```
val_by_vec = lambda x ,t=(): print(*[(x ,t[i]) for i in range(0,len(t))], sep="\n")
```

Also, that isn't an error, you are printing the generator object you've created